# How do I insert the a user's value into the first blank row if that value is not found in the column?

Tags: excel, vba

The main issue I have is that I can't determine what parameters should stop the search for the user's value in the first place. Below is the portion of my code that I'm working on

```
xrow = 1

For x = 1 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If InStr(1, ws1.Cells(x, 1), UserValue, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        ws1.Cells(x, 3) = ws2.Cells(20, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 4) = ws2.Cells(20, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 5) = ws2.Cells(20, 8).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 6) = Application.Sum(Range(ws1.Cells(x, 3), ws1.Cells(x, 5)))
        ws1.Cells(x, 7) = ws5.Cells(9, 8).Value
        StratTotal = ws1.Cells(x, 6).Value

        ws1.Cells(x, 8) = ws3.Cells(87, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 9) = ws3.Cells(87, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 10) = ws3.Cells(87, 8).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 11) = Application.Sum(Range(ws1.Cells(x, 8), ws1.Cells(x, 10)))
        ws1.Cells(x, 12) = ws5.Cells(9, 9).Value
        OpsTotal = ws1.Cells(x, 11).Value

        ws1.Cells(x, 13) = ws4.Cells(15, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 14) = ws4.Cells(15, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 15) = ws4.Cells(15, 8).Value
        ws1.Cells(x, 16) = Application.Sum(Range(ws1.Cells(x, 13), ws1.Cells(x, 15)))
        ws1.Cells(x, 17) = ws5.Cells(9, 10).Value
        CompTotal = ws1.Cells(x, 16).Value

        Cumulative = StratTotal + OpsTotal + CompTotal
        ws1.Cells(x, 2) = Cumulative
    ElseIf x >= 350 Then
        firstEmptyRow = ws1.Cells(x, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ws1.Cells(firsEmptyRow, 1).Value = UserValue

        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 3) = ws2.Cells(20, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 4) = ws2.Cells(20, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 5) = ws2.Cells(20, 8).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 6) = Application.Sum(Range(ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 3), ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 5)))
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 7) = ws5.Cells(9, 8).Value
        StratTotal = ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 6).Value

        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 8) = ws3.Cells(87, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 9) = ws3.Cells(87, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 10) = ws3.Cells(87, 8).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 11) = Application.Sum(Range(ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 8), ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 10)))
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 12) = ws5.Cells(9, 9).Value
        OpsTotal = ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 11).Value

        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 13) = ws4.Cells(15, 6).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 14) = ws4.Cells(15, 7).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 15) = ws4.Cells(15, 8).Value
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 16) = Application.Sum(Range(ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 13), ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 15)))
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 17) = ws5.Cells(9, 10).Value
        CompTotal = ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 16).Value

        Cumulative = StratTotal + OpsTotal + CompTotal
        ws1.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 2) = Cumulative

End If
```

Essentially, I'm searching through Column A of a worksheet to find a name that a user is entering, and if it's found I'm inserting values from another workbook's sheets into the columns of that row.

The portion mentioned in the previous paragraph works, but I also want to add functionality where after searching through that column and not finding the user's value, the macro adds that value (the name) to the first column, and then brings over the same values. I added an arbitrary stop of row 350 for the loop at the moment as I wasn't sure how else to go about it. Currently the value is not being inserted into the first blank row, and I worry that the arbitrary stopping point might be causing that to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could avoid scanning row by row and use `Find()` method of `Range` object to find the cell where `UserValue` possibly is:

```
Dim foundRng As Range
Set foundRng = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=UserValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

Moreover you can add the logic to manage the case no `UserValue` is found and  set `foundRng` to the first empty cells, if any, or in the next available empty row:

```
Dim foundRng As Range
With ws1 ' reference target sheet
    With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column A range from row 1 down to last not empty one
        Set foundRng = .Find(what:=UserValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) ' try and find UserValue in referenced range
        If foundRng Is Nothing And WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then Set foundRng = .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If foundRng Is Nothing Then Set foundRng = .Cells(.Count + 1)
    End With
End With
```

from then on `foundRng` is the same as your `ws1.Cells(x, 1)` and since you want to write into a consecutive cells range, you could take benefit of `Resize()` property of `Range` object and VBA `Array()` function and rewrite the "writing" block as follows:

```
    With foundRng ' reference found range
        .Value = UserValue

        ' write down all values from except those resulting from a sum, where you place a zero
        .Cells(1, 3).Resize(, 15).Value = Array(ws2.Cells(20, 6).Value, _
                                                ws2.Cells(20, 7).Value, _
                                                ws2.Cells(20, 8).Value, _
                                                0, _
                                                ws5.Cells(9, 8).Value, _
                                                ws3.Cells(87, 6).Value, _
                                                ws3.Cells(87, 7).Value, _
                                                ws3.Cells(87, 8).Value, _
                                                0, _
                                                ws5.Cells(9, 9).Value, _
                                                ws4.Cells(15, 6).Value, _
                                                ws4.Cells(15, 7).Value, _
                                                ws4.Cells(15, 8).Value, _
                                                0, _
                                                ws5.Cells(9, 10).Value)

        'calculate sums
        StratTotal = Application.Sum(.Cells(1, 3).Resize(, 3))
        OpsTotal = Application.Sum(.Cells(1, 8).Resize(, 3))
        CompTotal = Application.Sum(.Cells(1, 13).Resize(, 3))
        Cumulative = StratTotal + OpsTotal + CompTotal

        'fill cells with sum    
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = Cumulative
        .Cells(1, 6).Value = StratTotal
        .Cells(1, 11).Value = OpsTotal
        .Cells(1, 16).Value = CompTotal    
    End With
```

Comment: Would " If foundRng Is Nothing Then Set foundRng = .Cells(.Count + 1) " return the last blank row? If instead I was trying to find the first blank row how would I structure the statement (say they had values in A1, A2, and A4, but left A3 blank it would go to A3)

Comment: as per my written comments `Set foundRng = .Cells(.Count + 1)` makes you _"get the next cell below referenced range last one"_

Comment: see edited answer to manage different cases of `UserValue` not found . If my answer solved your question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, combined your answer with the other guy's to get the solution. Needed to get the UserValue to go into the first blank cell in the range, not the first blank cell after the range.

Comment: You are welcome. My solution first search for first blank cell in the range and, should it not be any, in the first blank cell after the range. What way did you combine out two answers? You may want to post it and let people know

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is nothing wrong with your logic for the check and the copy, so keep this part the same. The check I would add is a flag that indicates of the value was found, so like this:

```
Dim valueWasFound As Boolean
valueWasFound = False
For x = 1 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, ws1.Cells(x, 1), UserValue, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        '--- all your copying code goes here...

        '--- ... and set the flag to True
        valueWasFound = True
    End If
Next x
```

Now check the flag before the next part of your logic and make the copies into empty rows only if needed:

```
If valueWasFound Then
    '--- the same logic you have above... 
    firstEmptyRow = ws1.Cells(x, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ws1.Cells(firsEmptyRow, 1).Value = UserValue

    ...
End If
```

If it runs too slowly, you can consider copying your ranges into [memory-based arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Reading_from_a_Range_of_Cells_to_an_Array) which will give you a considerable speed improvement (if you have a large number of rows).

Comment: I may have mistaken part of my question. Currently if the value is found it does correctly insert all of the values into the columns to the right. However, if the value is not found, I haven't been able to insert the value into the first blank row of the column and then bring over the values.

So I think I would need a flag or sorts that would indicate when it's finished looking through all of the rows and hasn't found the value. I believe the one in the code you shared is false while it looks through the rows, and is only true after it has found a value.

Comment: My mistake... the last statement should read `If Not valueWasFound Then`

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I combined your answer with the other guy's to come up with a solution, thanks for the assistance.